# Output of openssl_public_encrypt() and openssl_private_encrypt()

Tags: php, encryption, openssl, public-key-encryption

I would like to know few things

- What is output of openssl_public_encrypt() and openssl_private_encrypt() functions?
- Output of above functions (Encrypted data), will that be web-safe?
- How can I transfer generated encrypted data between websites?

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation for these functions?

Comment: What do you mean by "web-safe"?

Comment: I think you should start in the very beginning with your question, and describe your actual requirements.

Answer (score 2):

`openssl_public_encrypt()` encrypts a message with a public key so that only the corresponding private key can decrypt it.  This is used for protecting information against being seen by people who shouldn't.

`openssl_private_encrypt()` encrypts a message with a private key so that it can be decrypted by anyone who has the corresponding public key.  This is *not* used for protecting information against unwanted eyes, it's used for making digital signatures to help verify that the data hasn't been modified.  You generally shouldn't use this function; use `openssl_sign()` and `openssl_verify()` instead.

Encryption and signing are typically used together:  you take your data, sign it (using `openssl_sign()`) with your own private key, and then encrypt it (using `openssl_public_encrypt()`) with the recipient's public key.  Send both the signature and the encrypted message to the recipient, and the recipient can decrypt the message (using `openssl_private_decrypt()`) with his private key, and verify the signature (using `openssl_verify()`) with your public key.  This ensures that no one can read *or* tamper with the message while it's in transit, which is probably what you mean by "web-safe".

As for transferring data between websites, you can do that in any way you want.  HTTP, FTP, email, API calls, whatever.  The whole point of encryption and signing is that you don't have to use any special means to transfer the message securely.

Comment: websafe means, can i use encrypted data as an argument in query-string  of my url or not?

Comment: It's binary data, not text, so you'd have to make sure it's properly escaped for use in a query string.  (Or you could convert it to text, e.g. using hex or base64.)  And you probably don't want to put a *large* amount of data in a URL query string.  But these considerations are true of anything you'd put in a query string; encrypted data is no different.